# Elasticsearch: Multiple keywords not searching all fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and having an issue when searching all fields with multiple keywords. For example if I search all my fields for the term: `foo` I get all my results back.

But if I search all fields for `foo bar` it is only returning results from one field that have foo and bar within when I know that there are items with foo in 1 field and bar in another field.

If I search all fields for `foo "bar"` it will work correctly and return all results from all fields, but really don't want to attempt to explain to users to user quotations on the second term.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
    "must": {
     "query_string": {
      "fields": ["heading, title, content, call_number"],
      "query": "foo bar",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [multi_match with cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-cross-fields) type. Try out the below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "foo bar",
      "type":       "cross_fields",
      "fields":     [ "heading", "title" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Results are:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "69109590",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "title": "bar"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "69109590",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "heading": "foo"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `combined_fields` search query

> The combined_fields query supports searching multiple text fields as if their contents had been indexed into one combined field. [readmore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-combined-fields-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "combined_fields": {
      "query": "foo bar",
      "fields": [
        "heading",
        "title",
        "content",
        "call_number"
      ],
      "operator": "and"
    }
  }
}
```